# Add a string row for matrix column headings

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to add a line with name of each column, for a matrix in Matlab?

For example I have this matrix

```
I =

203   397   313   420   
269   638   338   642    
270   316   526   336   
291   553   372   550    
296   797   579   774
```

I would like to have

```
I =

 X     Y     Z   weight   
203   397   313   420   
269   638   338   642    
270   316   526   336   
291   553   372   550    
296   797   579   774
```

Comment: consider to take a look into the documentaion, especially [Cell Arrays](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and/or [Tables](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a matrix: no. All matrix elements must be numerical.

[**`Tables`**](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) are the best option as you can keep the data formatted numerically (interact like you would for a matrix) but have headings...

```
% Set up matrix
I = [203   397   313   420   
     269   638   338   642    
     270   316   526   336   
     291   553   372   550    
     296   797   579   774];
% Convert to table
array2table(I, 'VariableNames', {'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'weight'})
```

[image: table]

When using tables, you can access the columns by their variable name like so:

```
disp(I.X)    % Prints out the array in the first column
disp(I(:,1)) % Exactly the same result, but includes the column heading

% For operations, reference the variables by name
s = I(:,1) + I(:,2); % Gives error
s = I.X + I.Y;       % Gives expected result
```

---

Note: according to the docs, tables were introduced in R2013b, if you have an older version of Matlab you will have to use cell arrays...

```
% Set up matrix as before
I = [203   397   313   420   
     ...   ...   ...   ...];   
% Convert to cell and add header row
I = [{'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'weight'}; num2cell(I)];
```

[image: cell array]

Comment: Thanks, I applied your first idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`table`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html):

```
X = [203, 269, 270, 291, 296];
Y = [397, 638, 316, 553, 797];
Z = [313, 338, 526, 372, 579];
weight = [420, 642, 336, 550, 774];

T = table(X, Y, Z, weight);
```

This is the result:

```
>> T

T = 

         X               Y               Z             weight   
    ____________    ____________    ____________    ____________

    [1x5 double]    [1x5 double]    [1x5 double]    [1x5 double]
```